# Using e.g. in citation

Tags: formatting

I am trying to place 'e.g.' in my citation. How do I place e.g. ahead of my intext citation? I have tried

```
\cite[e.g.,]{}{citation1, etc}
```

But it does not provide the needed output.

Comment: Did you try `\cite[e.g.][]{key1}`?

Comment: Please provide a complete example if you need help. We have no idea what output you need or what output you currently get.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load a citation management package, e.g., `natbib` or `apacite`. `natbib` modifies the `\cite` macro and lets you write

```
\citep[e.g.,][]{key}
```